# Py2exe executable on Windows says I don't have MSVCR90.dll even though I do

Tags: python, dll, pycharm, exe, py2exe

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) in order to make py2exe executable. But even though I followed the steps and there are the proper dlls in the project, when I try running the exe file, it still says that the dll is not available. Excluding them doesn't help either. Also, I'm using Pycharm and I don't know if the py2exe manages to catch the imports from the interpreter. I'm very confused with this whole thing and I need help. Thanks.

Edit: I put the msvcr90.dll in my dist folder, and I'm not getting the error anymore. However, now I'm getting another problem in that py2exe doesn't recognize the modules that I installed in my PyCharm interpreter. Do I need to download them onto my computer or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by copying the DLL in `%WINDIR%\system32` (where there's a system path). Then it worked fine. You say you "have it", but where is it?

Comment: *msvcr90.dll* (part of *VStudio2008*) is delivered as an **assembly** (it's linked into its clients *exe*s / *dll*s via a manifest file, which 3 characteristics - other than the name must be matched). *Ms* dropped this architecture due to the so called *DLL hell*. There are many *Google* results on these topics. Typically, assemblies are located in *%WINDIR%\WinSxS* (this one is placed there by the (*vcredist\*.exe*) installer). So you have to run that installer as a prerequisite of your module. Or -  a possibility that I didn't explore, include the required *dll*s + the manifest.

Comment: So in your dist folder contains a *Microsoft.VC90.CRT* folder containing 3 dlls (*msvc?90.dll*) and a *Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest*? Also, do you plan to distribute your app publicly (to customers)? If yes, you should be aware of the redistribution terms. The 2nd part seems a different question totally unrelated to this.